# In Alapin Sicilian 2... Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.cxd4 e6 what is the best plan for white?

Tags: sicilian-defense, repertoire

What is the best reply after

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 c5 2.c3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.cxd4 e6
```

I understand that this is definitely not the best move for black. Consulting some databases, I see that this move is still played even at a higher level, so I want to have some plan for it in my repertoire. Stockfish wants 5.d5. And this is the move I played in a recent game. I see that also Nc3 and Nf3 are good options with huge scores for white according to databases. Which of the moves would be easiest to play and what would be a good plan?

I am 1700 on lichess and my goal is to reach 2000 in the near future.